# Who sets $PATH environment variable?

Tags: bash, shell, path

After installation of linux distribution, I see `PATH` environment variable set with some standard folders holding some binaries only

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Does `/bin/bash` set this initial path? If yes, how does shell decide that these are the standard paths that give a start for a programmer?

Comment: It is determined and set by the distro developers, and inherited by the various shells (bash, zsh, etc).

Comment: Many distros use `/etc/profile` which is sourced when the shell is started